# How can we be balanced during a snatch?

Tags: weightlifting, workout, olympic-weightlifting, snatch

I'll take [this video of Lü Xiaojun](https://www.instagram.com/p/CSjsqf_lAKQ/?utm_medium=copy_link) as a reference.

Let's consider the power phase, that is the moment I'm curious to understand better.

[image]

At this point, his hips and the bar are very close to each other and both are close to the midfoot. I'd say that this allows him to be balanced around his midfoot.

Now, let's see the next moment.

[image]

In this picture, his hips are, as before, slightly behind his midfoot, whilst the bar is much more forwards than before. How can he be balanced?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He isn't.

If you tried to grab a bar in that position, you just wouldn't be able to, physics would object.

Even your first picture, I'd argue that he's not exactly "balanced" as I believe you mean it.

The snatch is a very explosive lift, it essentially goes from pulling a weight off the floor, to jumping with it, to catching it in a squat position, and it's  this catch in the squat position that is the most taxing on "balance".

When you catch the weight in a snatch, you're more pulling yourself under the bar into a squat position than pulling the weight towards you (again, physics makes this necessary; you don't want backwards momentum on the bar when you try and stop it, you won't win).

The freeze frame you're asking about is honestly kind of meaningless in the context of the question. If it helps, you can think of the movement as initial pull (balanced), floating bar (unbalanced), catch (balanced).

Comment: I'd just add, if you could measure the weight on his feet at that freeze frame (with bar above his waste) it is likely, momentarily, very close to 0.  The bar's momentum is carrying it up and his body is dropping down (pulling himself down)... as you said, no chance you could stop in that position and hold it (maybe an empty bar, but not with any weight on it).